# Unable to set library dependency in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, dll, shared-libraries

I have a project in Qt, with a class defined of the form

```
Project MyP  --- file p.h
#ifndef P_H
#define P_H

#include <QImage>

class PP
{
public:
   static QImage P1(const QImage& a);
}

#endif

Project MyP  --- file p.cpp

#include "p.h"

QImage PP::P1(const QImage& a)
{
   QImage b;
   return b;
}

I created a test project for the class above

project test, file test.h

#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <QtTest/QtTest>

class Test : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private slots:
    void TestSomething();

};

#endif 

#include "test.h"
#include "p.h"

void Test::TestSomething()
{
    QImage sourceImage = QImage("source.png");
    QImage newImage = PP::P1(sourceImage);

    int result = 1*2;
    QVERIFY(result == 2);
}

QTEST_MAIN(Test)
```

doing the same thing in c++ works but there I can easily add a lib dependency)... but in Qt i get an error

```
error: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6PPP1ENS_12P1MethodERK6QImage'
```

I tried to add library dependency like i saw here

http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_create_a_library_with_Qt_and_use_it_in_an_application

I added in the MyP header file

```
#if defined MYP_LIB
#define MYP_COMMON_DLLSPEC  Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#define MYP_COMMON_DLLSPEC Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif
```

and changed the class declaration to

```
class MYP_COMMON_DLLSPEC Dither
{
....
}
```

I added in the pro file ( I will post the entire file for ease)

```
TEMPLATE = lib
VERSION = 1.0.0.0
CONFIG += staticlib debug

debug   {
    DESTDIR = bin/debug
}
release {
    DESTDIR = bin/release
}

HEADERS += \
    pp.h

SOURCES += \
    pp.cpp 

DEFINES += MYP_LIB
```

then in the test project, I added in the pro file

```
DEPENDPATH += . ../myp
INCLUDEPATH += ../myp

win32:LIBS += ../myp/bin/debug/libmyp.a
LIBS+=  -L../myp/bin/debug -lmyp
```

I have been unable to create a lib file, or a dll file, and have been unable to get the projects to work together. Note: they are all in the same solution.

How can I properly run the test from a separate project ?

Comment: I edited the question and added the changes i made yesterday suggested the link i had posted - I already had these and it still was not working at the time I asked the question, that is why I am so confused

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the linker to import and export (respectively) a symbol from or to a DLL, so you have to declare your class like:

```
     Project MyP  --- file p.h
        #ifndef P_H
        #define P_H

       #if defined(MyP_LIBRARY)
       #  define MyPSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
       #else
       #  define MyPSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
       #endif

        #include <QImage>

        MyPSHARED_EXPORT class PP
        {
        public:
...
```

And add

```
DEFINES += MyP_LIBRARY
```

to your MyP.pro file

more information at
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sharedlibrary.html

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't state exactly what I did because I had to leave.. but I did add the Q_DECL_EXPORT/IMPORT directives and the DEFINES statement in the pro file - like it says in the link I posted. Still, building the library separately creates no lib or dll file. I am updating now the statements I added yesterday, in the question.